# Loop minicom scripts

Tags: serial-port, minicom

I need send AT commands to my modem (Huawei e171) in a loop.
I try this script (file script.txt):

```
start:
  send AT+CSQ
  sleep 2
  goto start
```

and run it via `minicom -S script.txt` but got nothing: empty minicom screen opened.
[image]
but script with single command works well:

```
start:
  send AT+CSQ
```

gives expected output:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

PS:
I try this script:

```
start:
  send AT+CSQ

  send AT+CSQ

  send AT+CSQ
```

but it gives only one answer from modem instead of three....

Answer (score 3):

Agree that "expect" is a workaround, not perfect though because it can only print the serial port output after it sees its expectation, if it does not see the expected keyword it does not print anything regardless of serial port output.

Below example sends "help" every 2 seconds and lasts 20 seconds, it expects "kann>" in the response to "help" command and print whatever characters before and including "kann>" after "help"

```
debian@bbb:~$ cat minicomscript.txt
verbose on
timeout 20
loop:
  send help
  expect "kann>"
  sleep 2
  goto loop
debian@bbb:~$ minicom -S minicomscript.txt
```

Comment: does anybody know how to print whatever that serial port outputs to screen with minicom runscript?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean what *you* send to the serial port isn't being echoed back? Or do you mean you want to send the serial port output to a printer?

Comment: the latter, although to screen/monitor instead of prunter

Comment: If what you send *is* being echoed to the screen, then it sounds like it's working properly already. It's how minicom works for me. I'm still confused because it doesn't sound like there's an issue here at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution `expect` keyword with expected result needed after command:

```
start:
  send AT+CSQ
  expect "OK"
  sleep 2
  goto start
```